# Drupal heartbeat delete function not working

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-7

I'm fixing a website built with drupal and there is a delete button not working

The console log is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'remove' of undefined

How to fix it?

Or how can I get to the button url link to write something myself, because I can find the record in the database, I can write a query to delete it directly, but I can't find the function.

The url is like:

```
heartbeat/nojs/activity/delete/7740?destination=user/46
```

I tried using the url directly, it will work. The link url has a class that trigs a JS, that JS is the problem.
Does anyone know how to delete all the class attributes of it?

I tested, if I delete all class, it will work, I think js is triggered by a class name, does anyone know how to manage class name in drupal?

Comment: Hi @Xuan Zhao did you get your solution on the above . I am facing the same issue with delete functionality of heartbeat comment

Comment: left that project long ago, sorry can't help you... gl buddy